# Passing variable between datatable functions

Tags: jquery, datatables

I set a global variable at the top of my page. 
    P_Col = '0';

I change this variable in the fnRowCallback function, and then try to use it in the aaSorting function, but aaSorting uses 0, it never get's the updated variable value from the callback function. can anyone help me with this?

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();  

        $.each(oSettings.aoColumns, function(i,value){ 
            if (value.sTitle == "Priority"){
              P_Col = i;
            };

            $.each(aData, function(ii,value2){
              if (value.sTitle == "Priority" && aData[i] != ""){
                  $('td:eq(' + i + ')', nRow).css('background-color', '#F6CED8');
                }   
            }); 
        });
    }  ,
    "aaSorting": [[P_Col, 'desc'], [12, 'asc']]
```

Answer (score 0):

aaSorting gets called during the creation of the datatable. fnRowCallback is called when the row is created after the creation of the datatable.

I would suggest using:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    var oTable= this;
    //Then Call sort based on your priority
    $.each(oSettings.aoColumns, function(i,value){ 
        if (value.sTitle == "Priority"){
            //P_Col = i;
            oTable.fnSort( [ [i,'asc'] ] );
        };
    }
```

Comment: I tried this without any success, unfortunately. Looks like you can't use fnSort within fnDrawCallback. The table fails to load.

Comment: Is thee a way you can p_col before you initialize the data table? Or you can call fnSort() after the initialize. If you post more complete code I may be able to offer other advise.

Comment: P_Col is set to '0' right after document ready, well before the table is initialized. If I call fnSort() after initialize, it uses the value of '0' I set earlier. fnRowCallback doesn't update the value in the variable for some reason. I am doing all of this so I can format data and sort based on the column name, not it's index. If I use ColReorder, the index will change and the formatting will get messed up.